# It keeps messing up when appending name of a file from a $_SESSION

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a problem appending the imageNameArray where it is suppose to display file names which have been uploaded.

The problem is that lets say I previously uploaded 3 files (cat.png, dog.png and pig.png), when I refresh page and upload another file (panda.png), then when I upload the file, it should display 'panda.png'. But instead it is just appending the names of the previously uploaded files (cat.png, dog.png and pig.png) and it does not append panda.png.

If I refresh page again and upload another file (tiger.png), then when I upload the file, it should display 'tiger.png'. But instead it is just appending the names of the previously uploaded files (cat.png, dog.png and pig.png and panda.png) and it does not append tiger.png.

If I upload another file (not refreshing page) such as monkey.png, then again it appends cat.png, dog.png and pig.png and panda.png. No monkey.png.

why is it messing up like this? All I want is that when a file is uploaded, it's name is appended but it doesn't want to do this :(

UPDATE:

Below is the javascript code where the appending occurs:

```
<?php
session_start();

$idx = count($_SESSION ['fileImage'] - 1);
$output = isset($_SESSION ['fileImage'][$idx]) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'][$idx]['name'] : "";

?>

          function stopImageUpload(success){

          var imageNameArray = new Array();
          imageNameArray = <?php echo $output ?>;
          var result = '';



          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';

                for(var i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++)
        {
             $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i]+ '<br/>');

         }

          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
          }

    return true;

    }
```

Below is the php script where it uploads a file which is on another page from the javascript function above:

```
    <?php

        session_start();

        $result = 0;
        $errors = array ();
        $dirImage = "ImageFiles/";


    if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

    $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );


    $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

            if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
                if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                    $result = 1;


                }
            }

        }

$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = array('name' => $_FILES ['fileImage']['name']);

        ?>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Comment: how are these files connected?  You are outputting something in javascript that comes from when a form is submitted with file input type.  I don't see how these two would be related.  You probably need to use $_SESSION to persist the name across pages.

Comment: I did relate them previously using $_SESSION but I had a problem with the way it displayed file names, I will add $_SESSION to the code and I will update question to tell you what is wrong when I use $_SESSION

Comment: I updated code to what it previously was with the $_SESSION and I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read up about $_SESSION.  It needs to be "started" on every page that needs access to the $_SESSION array.  you need to add

```
session_start()
```

to the page that is echo'ing out for the javascript too

Ok, then we need to change your appending implementation.

```
$_SESSION ['files'][] = array('name' => $_FILES ['fileImage']['name']);
```

and then to retrieve the last one,

(I would put this somewhere after session_start())

```
$idx = count($_SESSION ['files'] - 1);
$output = isset($_SESSION ['files'][$idx]) ? $_SESSION ['files'][$idx]['name'] : "";

...

imageNameArray = <?php echo $output ?>;
```

Comment: I do have session_start() on the same page as the javascript code. I want to append the names so that lets say you have uploaded 3 files, you can see the name of the 3 files you have uploaded to make sure they are correct.  But if I refresh the browser, I want them names to dissapear and start again.
Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: I have tested your answer but if I open up the web page, it just shows a blank page. Do you know why it is doing this? Could it be because of the [] in the $_SESSION? There is no javascript errors on error console and I don't php errors on screen. I updated code in the question so you can see what current code looks like